# NSDate returning wrong hour

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, timepicker

I am trying to get the hour from an NSDate object I'm using iOS 14.0.1 to run this code.

```
    NSDate *date = self.wakeUpView.timePicker.date;
    NSTimeInterval secondsFromGMT = [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
    NSLog(@"inital date selected: %@",date);
    NSDate *correctDate = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsFromGMT];
    NSLog(@"correct date: %@", correctDate);        //this is correct according to the time I selected
    NSLog(@"The hour I want: %ld",(long)correctDate.br_hour);    
    NSLog(@"Also tried: %ld",(long)[correctDate br_hour]);

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:correctDate];
    NSLog(@"formatted date: %@",dateString);
```

Here is the output:

```
inital date selected: 2020-09-29 14:34:00 +0000
correct date: 2020-09-29 22:34:00 +0000
The hour I want: 6
Also tried: 6
formatted date: 06:34
```

For this output, I selected 10:34 pm in the date picker.

displaying the minute works correctly using `correctDate.br_minute`. How can I get the correct hour? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time

Comment: You should set your timeZone only to the `dateFormatter`, no elsewhere, it's just for human interface.

Comment: I want to get the real hour I selected from the timePicker, as you can see from the `initial date selected` the time is wrong so I tried to change it to the correct time by using `correctDate`. That works but when I try to get the hour from that object the hour is wrong. If I remove the timeZone how can I get the correct hour I selected? Am I missing something? @Larme